# image is cropped and has rounded corners

Tags: image, imageview

I'm trying to load an image into an image view:

[image]

but the image is cropped inside the image view:

[image]

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@mipmap/icona_animal_app" />
```

why does this thing happen? how can i solve?
I've tried with all the values of the attribute "scaleType" like "fitcenter" but nothing works

Code of the activity:
I'm trying to load an image into an image view: enter image description here

but the image is cropped inside the image view:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    //dichiarazione oggetti
    TextInputEditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    Button buttonLogin;
    Button buttonLogRapido;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView TextView;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            //se l'utente è attualmente connesso vado alla main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //inizializzazione oggetti
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        buttonLogRapido = findViewById(R.id.btn_accesso);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        TextView = findViewById(R.id.registerNow);

        // vai alla schermata di selezione tipo utente da ragistrare
        TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrazioneMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
            }
        });

        // vai alla selezione utente con login automatico
        buttonLogRapido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccessoRapido.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        }) ;

        // effettua login da input
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String email, password;
                email = String.valueOf(editTextEmail.getText());
                password = String.valueOf(editTextPassword.getText());

                //controllo campi a video
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.insEmail),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.insPassword),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Utenti");
                                    ChatHelper.getIstance().notifyUnreadMessages(getApplicationContext());

                                    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.child("Padrone").child(user.getUid()).exists()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autEseguita),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                //se eseguito vado alla main activity
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePadrone.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            if (snapshot.child("Veterinario").child(user.getUid()).exists()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autEseguita),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                //se eseguito vado alla main activity
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeVeterinario.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            if (snapshot.child("Attivita").child(user.getUid()).exists()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autEseguita),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                //se eseguito vado alla main activity
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeAttivita.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            if (snapshot.child("Segnalatore").child(user.getUid()).exists()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autEseguita),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                //se eseguito vado alla main activity
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeSegnalatore.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            if (snapshot.child("Ente").child(user.getUid()).exists()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autEseguita),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                //se eseguito vado alla main activity
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeEnte.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.autFallita),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });

            }
        });


    }
}
```

why does this thing happen? how can i solve?
I've tried with all the values of the attribute "scaleType" like "fitcenter" but nothing works

code of the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".Autenticazione.Login">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/icona_animal_app" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/animalApp"
        android:textColor="#FF9800"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Accedi" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Non_hai_un_account"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registerNow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Registrati_ora"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_accesso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/accesso_rapido" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using android:scaleType="fitXY" for example see below:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:src="@mipmap/icona_animal_app" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. I also increased the size of the image view but it doesn't work